# PayPal ExpressCheckout Missing Total column

Tags: paypal, checkout

Why am I missing the total on the checkout page?

[image: Missing Totals]

Apologies.

As my code is working, because it actually got to PayPal and does have all the field correct.
I didn't think it was necessary to post the code.
I thought it could be answered simply, "you're missing the XXXX variable in your post to PayPal."

But, seeing as this is StackOverflow, code is required.

This is COLDFUSION (yes caps because people think this is a dead/dying language).

```
<cffunction name="expressCheckout" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="false" description="Processes PayPal Subscription">
    <cfargument name="L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="L_BILLINGTYPE0" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="AMT" type="numeric" required="yes" />

    <cfset var username = "wpp_1306278086_biz_api1.blahblah.com">
    <cfset var password = "1306278555">
    <cfset var signature = "someSig">
    <cfset var serverURL = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp">
    <cfset var version = "65.1">

    <cfset requestData = StructNew()>
    <cfset requestData.USER = "#USERNAME#">
    <cfset requestData.PWD = "#PASSWORD#">
    <cfset requestData.SIGNATURE = "#SIGNATURE#">
    <cfset requestData.SUBJECT = "">
    <cfset requestData.VERSION = "#version#">
    <cfset requestData.METHOD = "SetExpressCheckout">
    <cfset requestData.AMT = "#arguments.AMT#">
    <cfset requestData.DESC = "#arguments.L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0#">
    <cfset requestData.CUSTOM = "#session.rfcid#">

    <cfset requestData.returnURL = "http://localhost:8500/rfc2-1/membership/payPalConfirm.cfm">
    <cfset requestData.cancelURL = "http://localhost:8500/rfc2-1/membership/creditcardform.cfm">

    <cfset payPalReturn = doHttppost(requestData, serverURL, "no")>
    <cfset payPalReturn = getNVPResponse(#URLDecode(payPalReturn)#)>

    <cfif payPalReturn.ACK EQ "Failure">
        <!--- return the error message --->
        <cfset payPalReturn.ERRORMESSAGE = #payPalReturn.L_LONGMESSAGE0#>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn payPalReturn>

</cffunction>
```

This retuns a json object to the browser.
The browser then sends me to: 
https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=SomeToken

All fine when I get to PayPal.  Just missing the total in the left hand box (as diagrammed)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a guessing game, or are we supposed to use ESP to see your code? You posted absolutely no information that can be used to help you. Voting to close as "not a real question".

Answer (score 0):

Try appending &useraction=commit to the PayPal redirection URL (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxxx&useraction=commit).

Not sure of this works for billing agreements, but worth a shot. It'll work for regular payments anyway.

edit:
Actually, on second thought; since it's a billing agreement, which is not for a fixed price (otherwise you wouldn't need a billing agreement in the first place); this would be intended. Since there **is no** specific price to display.

Comment: Actually, on second thought; since it's a billing agreement, which is not for a fixed price (otherwise you wouldn't need a billing agreement in the first place); this would be intended. Since there **is no** specific price to display.